# cannot create a geopandas df

Tags: projection, geopandas, proj

I am trying to create a geopandas dataframe using the following code:

```
# designate coordinate system
crs = {'init':'espc:4326'}

# zip x and y coordinates into single feature
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(data2['longitude'], data2['latitude'])]

# create GeoPandas dataframe
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, crs = crs, geometry = geometry)
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
Invalid projection: +init=espc:4326 +type=crs: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: cannot expand +init=espc:4326 +type=crs)
```

I really don't have a clue of what is happening. Can anyone help me to understand what's going wrong here? This code was not written by me but appears to have worked in the past.

Comment: It's `"espg"` not `"epsc"`

Comment: Thank you, I already corrected the mistake but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: if you're getting the exact same error, you didn't correct the mistake

Comment: https://geopandas.org/projections.html

Comment: You're right because it's neither `epsc` nor `espg`, it's `epsg`.